# Flutter ListView.builder and Provider unexpected behavior

Tags: flutter

Before using `Provider`, i was sending the data through the widgets. But now when i moved everything to `provider` i get some issues with `ListView.builder`. Such as when i `hot reload` It shows same `quote` instead of the different `quotes`. Also i feel i'm approaching this in the wrong way, like it replace the `quote` with the last one. So if i would like edit a `quote` in the `list` it will think it's the last quote.

I made the code shorter, what i'm actually doing. But it's serving the same purpouse.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Provider(
            create: (_) => QuoteProvider(),
            child: const _BuildQuoteListView(),
        );
    }
}

class _BuildQuoteListView extends StatelessWidget {
    const _BuildQuoteListView();
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final provider = Provider.of<QuoteProvider>(context, listen: false);
        return Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: provider.quotes.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    provider.text = provider.quotes[index];
                    return const _DisplayQuote();
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}

class _DisplayQuote extends StatelessWidget {
    const _DisplayQuote();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final provider = Provider.of<QuoteProvider>(context, listen: false);
        return Center(
            child: Text(provider.text)
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the provider:

```
class QuoteProvider {
    String text;
    List<String> quotes = ["Red apple taste better than a green apple.", "Teach someone to fish and feed them for a lifetime.", "Snow is melt water?"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you see the same `quote`, your code works for me. However, I would not pass the current quote to `_DisplayQuote` in the `provider`. instead I would either pass the `quote` or the `index` as an argument to the widget. Passing the `index` will let the widget update the correct `quote` in the `provider` if and when you add that functionality. For example:

```
      // provider.text = provider.quotes[index];
      return _DisplayQuote(index);
```

and:

```
class _DisplayQuote extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  const _DisplayQuote(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<QuoteProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return Center(child: Text(provider.quotes[index]));
  }
}
```